# OAuth2.0 Support In Liferay JSON Web Services

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, liferay, liferay-6

I have created two API through service builder as given below

```
public class PrescriptionServiceImpl extends PrescriptionServiceBaseImpl {

    @AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled = true)
    public String freeService(){
        return "free service";
    }

    public String privateService(){
        return "private service";
    }
}
```

I want to authenticate the second service with OAuth 2.0 since the first service is already on guest mode. Does Liferay 6.2 support OAuth 2.0 token based authentication apart from Basic Authentication? If so please help me how to proceed further.

These are the HTTP URL created by Liferay for above two services

```
http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/Prescription-portlet.prescription/free-service

http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/Prescription-portlet.prescription/private-service
```

Answer (score 1):

Liferay 6.x does not support OAuth 2 for /api/jsonws service access.

You would need to implement your own AuthVerifier implementation for OAuth 2 and add it to the list declared in portal-ext.properties.

Comment: Hi @dnebing, Thanks for the lead. I've implemented whatever you have suggested. Can you tell me further how can i test my rest apis?